# PHP sendo comentado dentro do JS

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

O código é este:

```
   success: function (result) {
      var tbody = $('tbody');
      tbody.html('');

      $.each(result, function(k, value) {
        search += "<tr class='tagtr'>";
          search += "<td>" + value.description + "</td>";
          search += "<td>" + value.initial + "</td>";
          search += "<td>" + value.email + "</td>";
          search += "<td>" + value.url + "</td>";
          search += "<td id='table_status' class='text-center'><?= convertStatus(" + value.status + "); ?></td>";
          search += "<td class='text-center'>";
            search += "<button class='btn btn-red-dark' onclick='location=\"alter?q=" + value.id + "\"'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit' aria-hidden='true'></span></button>";
          search += "</td>";
        search += "</tr>";
      });

      tbody.append(search);
   },
   error: function(result) {
      $('#alert').addClass('alert alert-danger').html().show('100');
   }
});
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que posso fazer para deixar de comentar???

Comment: use a tag <?php ?>

Comment: já tentei não funcionou.

Answer (score 7):

Isso não vai funcionar. O PHP é processado pelo Servidor, enquanto o código JavaScript nesse caso é processado pelo Cliente (Browser). Você pode criar um looping no PHP para escrever código JavaScript, mas não é possível fazer o inverso (que é o seu caso). Ou você faz uma requisição AJAX para o Servidor pedindo para ser executado essa função em PHP ou você cria uma função no JavaScript para ser chamada em vez de tentar chamar funções do PHP.